# Group By but Keep All Sets of Data MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have data stored in a database and I'm selecting based on the slug field.

There are some instances where 2 items will both have the same slug, in these cases I'd like to essentially do a `group by slug` although I'd still like both sets of data to be returned somehow, maybe creating a sub array of the 2 rows?

Is there any way to do this. If my explanation isn't clear I can try to further explain.

Comment: You may `ORDER BY slug`, and in your PHP application code, you use your display loop to determine if the value has changed, and act accordingly. SQL is only able to produce a 2 dimensional rowset. Alternatively, you may look at [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), which could produce delimited strings of other columns, but you will still need to use your PHP code to split the concatenated group and do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit based on your comment --

If you want the values brought up as separate columns, you can use a variable:

Given example data:

```
create table slugs
(
    item    varchar(20),
    slug    varchar(20)
);

insert into slugs values ('Item A','Slug A');
insert into slugs values ('Item B','Slug A');
insert into slugs values ('Item C','Slug B');
insert into slugs values ('Item D','Slug A');
insert into slugs values ('Item E','Slug A');
insert into slugs values ('Item F','Slug A');
insert into slugs values ('Item G','Slug A');
insert into slugs values ('Item H','Slug A');
```

Run:

```
select   slug,
         min(if(rn=1,item,null)) as item_1,
         min(if(rn=2,item,null)) as item_2,
         min(if(rn=3,item,null)) as item_3,
         min(if(rn=4,item,null)) as item_4,
         min(if(rn=5,item,null)) as item_5,
         min(if(rn=6,item,null)) as item_6,
         min(if(rn=7,item,null)) as item_7
from(
select   @rn:=case when @slug=slug then @rn+1 else 1 end as rn,
         @slug:=slug as slug,
         item
from     slugs cross join (select @rn:=0,@slug:='') r
order by slug
) x
group by slug;
```

Output:

```
|   slug | item_1 | item_2 | item_3 | item_4 | item_5 | item_6 | item_7 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| Slug A | Item A | Item B | Item D | Item E | Item F | Item G | Item H |
| Slug B | Item C | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

(Add an IF for each additional possible item, ie. if there are at most 10 items for a given slug, add 3 more)

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5832/4/0

Alternatively, if you don't care about the values being in separate columns, you can more simply use `group_concat`:

```
select   slug,
         group_concat(item) as items
from     slugs
group by slug;
```

Output:

```
|   slug |                                            items |
|--------|--------------------------------------------------|
| Slug A | Item A,Item B,Item D,Item E,Item F,Item G,Item H |
| Slug B |                                           Item C |
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5832/3/0

Comment: What if instead of simply 1 item, I have around 7 - 8 other fields I would like to return?